# Javascript/Jquery slider change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so here's the problem. I suck at jquery but I'm trying to get better. I have a jquery ui range slider, works well. But I'm trying to add a change function so that when the values are changed, it puts the min age value into one text box, and the max age into another. Everything above the "change" block works fine,  But as soon as i add the block from "change :" downwards to the code, slider fails to appear and I have an obvious error. I've tried this 20 different ways based on online tutorials and I just can't figure out why it's not working.

```
 $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 18,
      max: 90,
      
      values: [ <?php echo htmlentities($row_loggedinUser['minAge']) ?>,<?php echo htmlentities($row_loggedinUser['maxAge']) ?> ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {$( "#amount" ).val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );}}),
      
      change: function(event, ui){
            var x = document.getElementById('minAgeAmt');
            x.value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
            var y = document.getElementById('maxAgeAmt');
            y.value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );  
      };
```

********* EDIT ***********

Now thanks to Leighton it's working, just one issue . I now have this :

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
range: true,

min: 18,
max: 90,
values: [ <?php echo htmlentities($row_loggedinUser['minAge']) ?>,<?php echo htmlentities($row_loggedinUser['maxAge']) ?> ],
slide: function( event, ui ) {$( "#amount" ).val("Age Range : " + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);},
change: function(event, ui) {
    var x = document.getElementById('minAgeAmt');
    x.value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
    var y = document.getElementById('maxAgeAmt');
    y.value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );
```

}

});

Which works nice, but the bit where the #amount element is given a value only fires (obviously) when a change is made. How can I get it to also fire initially on page load? At the moment when the page loads it looks like this :

[image]

and as soon as I change the slider, :

[image]

I simply want the same caption generated on page load based on initial values

Comment: Did you look at the console to see if there were errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 18,
    max: 90,

    values: [ <?php echo htmlentities($row_loggedinUser['minAge']) ?>,<?php echo htmlentities($row_loggedinUser['maxAge']) ?> ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);
    },

    change: function(event, ui) {
        var x = document.getElementById('minAgeAmt');
        x.value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
        var y = document.getElementById('maxAgeAmt');
        y.value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );  
    }
});
```

---

**Part 2**

For setting the 'amount' value, under the code above you could try:

```
// This gets the current values which you have set above
var values = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "option", "values" );
$("#amount").val(values[0] + " - " + values[1]);
```

Refer https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-values

Comment: an add on query for you Leighton if you don't mind, inserted into the question above...

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error, you missed the `)` in the last line

 Updated coding

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 18,
      max: 90,

      values: [ <?php echo htmlentities($row_loggedinUser['minAge']) ?>,<?php echo htmlentities($row_loggedinUser['maxAge']) ?> ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {$( "#amount" ).val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );},

      change: function(event, ui){
            var x = document.getElementById('minAgeAmt');
            x.value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 );
            var y = document.getElementById('maxAgeAmt');
            y.value = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 );  
      }
});
```

Comment: That's what I saw, too, but in your proposed solution you're closing the `change` function but not the `slider` function so it will still throw an error.

Comment: sorry guys, I do in fact have all of those extra ) and }, I just didn't include them when I cut and pasted

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax errors please find below snippet for more info you have to put `change function` just before `slider` function is closed

```js
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 18,
    max: 90,

    values: [],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        var x = document.getElementById('minAgeAmt');
        x.value = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
        var y = document.getElementById('maxAgeAmt');
        y.value = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
    } //close change function
}); //close Slider Function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use following

For min value

```
var min = $("#slider-range").slider("option", "min");
```

For max value

```
var max = $("#slider-range").slider("option", "max");
```